# Run a JavaScript App on Salesforce Community page

Tags: javascript, community, xml, digital-experience

A 3rd party wrote a very simple JavaScript web app.  I have HTML code, the JavaScript file, and an XML file.  I am wondering if there is a way to use this on a Salesforce Community page without rewriting anything in LWC, etc.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can. The `lightning-container` element allows you to host an entire web app in React, Svelte, Angular, etc, and have it safely exposed in Lightning Experience and Builder Sites.

For this, you'll need three lines of code.

First, upload the file into a static resource (Setup | Custom Code | Static Resources).

Next, make a new Aura component. Make the component available to communities, and using the index.html for your app:

```
<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global">
  <lightning:container src="{!$Resource.myReactApp + '/index.html'}"/
</aura:component>
```

Finally, go to your Builder, find the Aura component, and place it wherever you'd like. Make sure you Publish your changes when you're ready.

Check out the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:container/documentation) for more details.

Comment: Do I have to disable Lightning Locker for this to work?

Comment: @MicheleKleinhomer It should be compatible with both security models. I haven't tried it in Experience Builder, though. Are you having trouble getting it to work?

Comment: I am just starting to work on it.  I had a bad static resource setup & got an injection error.  That made me question this.  I am still working on it.  I will let you know how I make out.

Comment: Please see update at bottom of question.

Comment: @MicheleKleinhomer Make sure you edit your question, and not the answer. I'll be happy to take a look at it with you.

Comment: @MicheleKleinhomer That said, if you're able, send me the zip file and I should be able to spot the problem.

Comment: I edited the question but it says it is in the pending status.  How do I send you a zip file (via email, etc.?)  Thanks for your help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145471/discussion-between-michele-kleinhomer-and-sfdcfox).

Comment: I moved this discussion to a chat.  Let me know if you have trouble seeing it.